# Bootstrap tabs with Datatables TableTools

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, export-to-excel, tabletools

I am using Datatable TableTools version 2.2.4. and Bootstrap v3.0.0. I am trying to export table in Bootstrap tab to CSV, XLS and PDF. I am using this code:

```
 tableTools: {
                "sSwfPath": instance.SwfUrl, 
                "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "mColumns": [ 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6]
                }]
             },
```

The problem is, that the table is in tab, which means it is not visible during initialization. If I put table out of tabs, it is working like a charm.

I googled this problem and the solutions were like this:

```
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
        var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
        if (table.length > 0) {
            $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
            var oTableTools = TableTools.fnGetInstance(table[0]);
            if (oTableTools != null && oTableTools.fnResizeRequired()) {
                oTableTools.fnResizeButtons();
            }
        }
    });
```

I am sure, that this event is fired but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Please post your whole code

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible.There is too much code around. I know exactly where is the problem. It is because the table is not visible during initialiation TableTools. Do you know, how to initializate function for export when the table is visible?

Comment: Normally with `$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {`, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JS

```
if ($('#TableID').is(':visible')) {
    InitTableTools($(this))
    // $(this) --> passes the table object if visible.
    //So that you can initialize table tools for that particular visible table only
}
else
{
DestroyTableTools($(this))// $(this) --> passes the table object if visible
}

function InitTableTools(Table)
{
 // code to initialize table tools 
}
funtion DestroyTableTools()
{
// code to destroy the initialised table tools , if destroy option is available in plugin
}
```